# how to run dell command-configure

Tags: dell

I've downloaded and installed command-configure using dpkg, but when I run the command `command-configure` I'm getting

> command not found

when running `apt list --installed | grep configure` I'm getting

> command-configure/now 3.3.0 amd64 [installed,local]

Answer (score 2):

Ok I did:

`sudo find / -name "cctk"` (found out this is the command name)

Then apparently it is in `/opt/dell/dcc/cctk`

To run:

```
cd /opt/dell/dcc;
sudo ./cctk
```

You're expected to see list of commands.
If instead you're seeing an error, and you just might, if your ubuntu is 22+; this thread might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133316/libssl-so-1-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory (if you're having the same error as me)

Download from here: https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000178000/dell-command-configure

And according to this doc: https://dl.dell.com/topicspdf/command-configure_users-guide4_en-us.pdf

> On the systems running Ubuntu Core, Dell Command | Configure can be accessed from any location using the
> following command: dcc.cctk

Answer (score 0):

You can `cd /opt/dell/dcc/cctk`

```
ls
```

and then

```
 sudo ./cctk
```