# How to run dell command-configure with the terminal?

Tags: dell

I successfully downloaded the [Dell Command | Configure](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln311302/dell-command-configure?lang=en) but if I run the "cctk" command it says:

```
Command 'cctk' not found, did you mean:

  command 'cct' from deb proj-bin (5.2.0-1)
  command 'sctk' from deb sctk (2.4.10-20151007-1312Z+dfsg2-3)
  command 'cmtk' from deb cmtk (3.3.1p1+dfsg-1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

The executable seems to be in `/opt/dell/dcc/cctk` ([see other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/996548/how-to-run-dell-command-configure/996552#996552)). If I run the executable another error appears:

```
Usage error.

Dell Command Configure Version 4.2.0  553 (Linux - Mar 20 2019, 11:35:21)
Copyright 2009 - 2019 Dell Inc. All rights reserved.

Usage: cctk --option[=argument]

For more information about a particular command, 
use the option '-H' followed by the command name.
Example: cctk -H --Asset
...
```

Any way to get it running?
Thank you!

Comment: It *is* running - if you're asking about command usage, there's documentation here: [Dell Command | Configure Version 4.2 Command Line Interface Reference Guide](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/ca/en/cadhs1/command-configure-v4.2/dcc_cli_4.2/options-for-dell-command-configure-42)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to change the [thermal management](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/power-manager/dpm_ug/thermal-management?guid=guid-d6b7de5c-0b5c-4594-83e6-063ec77ed108&lang=en-us) to "quiet"?

Comment: No I don't - sorry

Answer (score 4):

To make the binaries from `dcc` discoverable without having to type the full path every time, open the file `~/.bashrc` and add the following to the end,

```
export PATH="/opt/dell/dcc:$PATH"
```

Then when you open a new terminal, simply `cctk` will look for and execute this file in `/opt/dell/dcc`.

As for the actual usage, you’ll have to read the manual or help guide to understand how it works. `usage error` means the program was executed, but did not have the required command line arguments passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to add [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to your `/usr/local/sbin` directory.

```
$ sudo ln -s /opt/dell/dcc/cctk /usr/local/sbin/
```

Check the link

```
$ type cctk
cctk is /usr/local/sbin/cctk
```